# Unbind all mouseover events on window scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, bind, unbind

I have tried this code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.media-in').bind('mouseover',function(){
        $(this).children('.media-options').show();
    });
    $('.media-in').bind('mouseout',function(){
        $(this).children('.media-options').hide();
    });
    $(window).on('scroll',function(){
        $('.media-in').unbind('mouseover');
    });
});
```

It doesn't works as expected. I would like to `unbind` the event happening on `mouseover` when I scroll the page, how can I do that?

Also, is there any way to `unbind` events on the page scrolling by array? Something like:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ 
    $(this).unbind(['mouseover','click','mouseout']);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7, [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) and [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) are the preferred methods to bind and unbind event handlers.

So to remove all handlers from an element, use this:

```
$('.media-in').off();
```

or for specific handlers:

```
$('.media-in').off('mouseover mouseout click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on()` and `off()`, but once the event handler is removed, it won't magically return once you've stopped scrolling, you would have to rebind it again with `on()`.

```
$(function(){
    var timer;
    media_bind();

    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
         clearTimeout(timer);
         $('.media-in').off('mouseover mouseout');
         timer = setTimeout(media_bind, 500);
    });

    function media_bind() {
         $('.media-in').on(
             mouseover: function() {
                 $(this).children('.media-options').show();
             },
             mouseout: function() {
                 $(this).children('.media-options').hide();
             }
         });
    }  
});
```